# Does angular allow in-HTML scripts?

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs

So, for the past week, I've been trying to calculate the sum of data values in a single column (like a total) in Angular + FireStore, but here's the problem... It just doesn't work. I've tried coming up with some work-arounds based on articles I found online and questions posted here on SO but all to no good.

I'm from a PHP/JS (+ JQuery) background and with things like this it's a breeze to accomplish, I just feed the individual values to some sub array or a temporary variable (say total) in my PHP (sometimes in my JS) and push that value to the intended cell. Here I've had to subscribe to an RxJS stream and print the returned values to my HTML which is cool and all, but I cannot seem to get the total to work without needing to: go back to my component.ts file, create a new class property, re-subscribe to the RxJS stream and sum up the total from there; My problem is that before now every major project I've worked on are Enterprise grade and sometimes I'll have up to 2000+ records fetched at once (like that of the sales made for a week) and the page is sometimes slow to retrieve this, some of them have subtotals for the day, total for a branch, then a grand total of everything, so does it mean with Angular I'll have to load this data twice just to get these sums?

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated

**service.ts**

```
loadItems(coll:string): Observable<Expenses[]> {
    return this.db.collection(coll).snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(dump => {
        return dump.map(a => {
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Expenses;
          const resp:Expenses = {
            id: id,
            title: data.title,
            amount: data.amount,
            type: data.type,
            status: data.status
          }
          return resp;
        })
      })
    );
  }
```

**component.ts**

```
expenseData$ = this.exService.loadItems('expdata');
```

**component.html**

```
<tr *ngFor="let exp of expenseData$ | async; let i = index">
  <!-- {{ sub += exp.amount }} Something like this -->
  <td>{{ i + 1 }}</td>
  <td>{{ exp.title }}</td>
  <td>{{ exp.type }}</td>
  <td class="text-end">{{ exp.amount | currency:'N' }}</td>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="3">Total</td>
  <td class="text-end">{{ total | currency: 'N' }}</td> <!-- Problem's here... -->
  <!-- {{ sub = 0 }} to reset the subtotal -->
</tr>
```

Please how can I achieve this, I have a strong feeling it has something to do with RxJS, but I cannot seem to be able to put my finger on it

Comment: as per my understanding you want to make total of const resp:Expenses -> amount field right? without making another call of loadItems method

Comment: exactly, and it should (preferably be in the HTML) @Parth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach than create a new observable use "pipe(tap)".

```
expenseData$=this.exService.loadItems('expdata').pipe(
    tap((expenses:any[])=>{
       const total=expenses.reduce((value, item) => value + item.amount , 0)
       this.total=total
    })
)
```

And use `{{total| currency: 'N' }}`

Comment: This is what I am trying to avoid (creating something new, especially an RxJS stream), since I'm mostly going to be working with huge, resource consuming data from the server

Comment: a pipe tap not consuming data from server it's only execute a function (in local) when the observable change, and execute a loop over an array is really quick. The another response (using ShareReply) also not call to the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a second observable:

```
...
import { map, shareReplay ... } from 'rxjs';


totalAmount$ = this.expenseData$.pipe(
   map(expenses => expenses.reduce((total, value) => total + value, 0))
);
```

Then you can use `totalAmount$ | async` in your html-template to display the total amount.

To avoid a second server-request you should add a shareReplay(1) to the expenseData$-Observable:

```
expenseData$ = this.exService.loadItems('expdata').pipe(shareReplay(1));
```

Otherwise the `totalAmount$ | async` in your template would trigger a second server-request (because a subscription to totalAmount$ creates a subscription to expenseData$, which triggers a request)

Comment: Nice, but what about in scenarios like I pointed out in the question where I might need a daily sub-total for certain sales data from what's available in a database, then further sum up all these subs into a total for a branch, and at the end a grand total for the entire sales for a specified date range.

Comment: Everything which can be calculated from the data returned by loadItems() can be calculated by piping the expenseData$-stream and mapping the expenses to something else. You may derive as many streams from expenseData$ as you need (due to the shareReplay(1) that would not trigger new server-requests)

Comment: I can't seem to follow the explanation here, maybe my explanation was off. So, I mostly have huge data in a single table that companies print for ref. in this data, I might have 3 totals of which only 1 is independent, the rest depend on values calculated from before. (e.g 3 days sales for 3 outlets of a company with subtotal of sales for each day, total sales by each outlet in these 3 days, and a grand total of sales in made throughout. Then present these appropriately in the view).